# Lip balm pen, inquiring about its international eligibility

Tags: international, legal-status, us8596897

In reference to the patent: [US 8,596,897 B2](https://www.google.com/patents/US8596897)

I am inquiring to the eligibility of this patent in the UK.

Also checking if this patent was passed and taken into effect.

Comment: I edited out the part asking about distributors in the UK as that is off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

This patent issued on November 13, 2013 and is enforceable in the United States. There was no international application filed, so manufacture and sales outside of the US do not infringe. However, any sales within the US (including unintentional 3rd party sales) could lead to infringement or contributory infringement.

Since this site is not a direct connection to the patent holder or inventor, you will need to do your own research to find out about manufacturers and distributors. A good place to start is usually the [USPTO Assignee database](http://assignment.uspto.gov/#/search?q=8596897); however, there have been no assignments yet and the patent is currently assigned to the inventor.